# Windows 7 temporarily routes UDP packets for local network to default gateway

Tags: sockets, networking, windows-7, udp, ip

I have a Windows service running on a multi-homed Windows 7 machine communicating via UDP to a machine on the local network. This works fine, except sometimes during Windows startup the network traffic is temporarily (30 seconds) being routed to the default gateway, resulting in UDP packet loss. This packet loss is not necessarily a problem, but leads to an unnecessarily long startup time of the application.

The service binds to the socket using INADDR_ANY. Now when I change this to bind to the IP address of the control network NIC (192.168.32.1) I don't observe the problem. However I don't understand why the binding matters in this situation, and also I don't understand why the problem is there only temporarily. Do any of you have an explanation for this?

Besides my curiosity to find the root cause of this issue, I would also like to get an answer to this question so I can remove the bind to the specific IP address from my code. This decouples my application code from the network layout.

Network details:

- Machine A, Windows 7, two NICs:

  - NIC #1 (ext network): 192.168.116.x/23 (DHCP), gateway 192.168.117.1
  - NIC #2 (int network):  192.168.32.1/26 (fixed)
- Machine B, VxWorks, one NIC:

  - NIC #1 (int network):  192.168.32.16/26 (DHCP, assigned by Machine A)

Answer (score 0):

When using INADDR_ANY, you bind your socket to the default IP address - the one with the lowest interface address. From the symptomps you are describing, it seems like this interface is not yet configured during startup, which makes sense.

The question is, why do you bind sending socket to any address at all. Implicit binding during `send` should be OK for you, I imagine?

Comment: The first `sendto()` on an unbound datagram socket will do the equivalent of a `bind()` to INADDR_ANY, so the resulting behavior will be identical.

Comment: @keithmo would it? Is it specified to behave EXACTLY this way? Since it is deep internals of the operating system, I would not be surprised to learn that it will not bind to INADDR_ANY, but instead will bind to first usable interface, and INADDR_ANY to be deemed unusable. Not sure.

Comment: The MSDN documentation for sendto (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740148(v=vs.85).aspx) is a little cryptic. They say "If a socket is opened, a setsockopt call is made, and then a sendto call is made, Windows Sockets performs an implicit bind function call.", which is rather odd (setsockopt has nothing to do with this). They then say "If the socket is unbound, unique values are assigned to the local association by the system, and the socket is then marked as bound."

Comment: FWIW, I co-wrote several Winsock implementations (including the Winsock 1.1 that shipped with Windows 95 and the Winsock 2.2 that shipped with NT 4.0) and I chaired the "architectural framework" committee of the Winsock 2 standardization effort. That said, my direct knowledge of this is a little stale -- it's possible MS changed the behavior in later Windows versions, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: @keithmo, so it was YOU who prefixed all BSD functions with this terrible WSA  prefix for no reason?? Good to know!

Comment: LOL -- Winsock 1.1 was cast in stone when I joined the project, so it was not **entirely** my fault.

Comment: @keithmo - on any rate - pleased to meet you. Being one of the authors of WinSock implementation is trully something to be proud of. (No joking, serious).

Comment: Honestly, this question has been a good wake-up call for me. My comment above (about auto-binding on sendto) was almost an instinctive response because I **know** that's how it is (or at least that's how it used to be). I need to be more careful about checking publicly-available documentation before I spout such things.

Comment: @keithmo, inside knowledge is actually priceless! :)